# Onclick javascript - передать this клика

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Html**

```
onclick="photoRemove(this, 'url');
```

**Есть такая функция:**

```
function photoRemove(ev, dataPhoto){
ev.closest('div').remove(); // Не сработало
}
```

Почему на сработало: `ev.closest('div').remove();`

Comment: 1. не вешайте события onclick в html, особенно используя jquery.
2. ev тут - DOM элемент, а не jquery объект. у него нет метода closest.

Comment: Как тогда быть? как правильно?

Comment: Примерно [вот так][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/yZ9HT/